# vibration under car

Tags: hyundai, vibration, elantra

i have a 2014 Hyundai Elantra. car was driving great at 65mph, then i had to slow down without touching my brake. as i was coming down past 60 it starting vibrating. i felt the underneath of me vibrating but not in the steering wheel. then as i went to accelerate it made a terrible hard loud type vibration and immediately was fine after that. it did this two more times, same speed within mins of each other,same driving situation. now it’s vibrating all the time but not in the steering wheel. any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: Before you drive again, check that all the lug nuts are properly tightened. Loose lug nuts can cause your symptoms.

Is it mud season in your area? Check all four wheels for a buildup of mud. (Ice / snow can give the same result.) Be sure to also check the sides of the wheels that you can't see unless you get down on hands and knees and peek around the tires.

If you find mud, hose it off and that should take care of it.